# Calculate integral over $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 2z=x^2+y^2<\sqrt{z} \}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$\int\limits_{S} \sqrt{\frac{z}{1+2z}} \, d \sigma_S,$$ where $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \; | \; 2z=x^2+y^2<\sqrt{z} \}$.